Cauchy's inequality in Iwaniec's papers
I am working through Iwaniec's Fourier coefficients of modular forms of half-integral weight and encountered an inequality I don't quite understand. Iwaniec refers to it as Cauchy's inequality, which I suppose is related to the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality. He states
\begin{align*}
& \left ( \sum _{A/2P<a\leq 2A/P} \sum _{B<b\leq 2B} \left | \sum _{P_1<p\leq P_2} \lambda_p\left ( \frac{\pm nr}{p} \right ) e \left (2n \left( \frac{\overline{apr}}{b}-\frac{\overline{br}}{ap}+\frac{s\overline{apb}}{r}+\frac{\nu}{apbr} \right ) \right ) \right | \right )^2 \\ &\ll ABP^{-1}\sum_{p_1}\sum_{p_2}\left | \sum_{a}\sum_{b} e \left ( 2n(p_2-p_1) \left (\frac{\overline{ap_1p_2r}}{b}-\frac{\overline{br}}{ap_1p_2}+s\frac{\overline{ap_1p_2b}}{r}+\frac{\nu}{ap_1p_2br} \right ) \right ) \right |.
\end{align*}
Here $A,B,P,P_1$ and $P_2$ are fixed natural numbers, $\lambda_p$ is a complex sign, $\left (\frac{\pm nr}{p} \right)$ is a Kronecker symbol, $e(z)=exp(2\pi iz)$ and $\frac{\overline{u}}{v}$ means $u\overline{u} \equiv 1 (\mod q)$. I believe he is using Cauchy-Schwarz on some bilinear form given by a double or triple sum but I'm not sure. Any help would be appreciated.

By Cauchy--Schwarz,
$$\left(\sum_a \sum_b \left | \sum_p \lambda_p\left ( \frac{\pm nr}{p} \right ) e \left (2n \left( \frac{\overline{apr}}{b}-\frac{\overline{br}}{ap}+\frac{s\overline{apb}}{r}+\frac{\nu}{apbr} \right ) \right ) \right | \right )^2 \leq \left(\sum_a \sum_b 1\right) \left(\sum_a \sum_b \left | \sum_p \lambda_p\left ( \frac{\pm nr}{p} \right ) e \left (2n \left( \frac{\overline{apr}}{b}-\frac{\overline{br}}{ap}+\frac{s\overline{apb}}{r}+\frac{\nu}{apbr} \right ) \right ) \right |^2\right).$$
The first term is $\ll ABP^{-1}$. For the second, we open up the square, yielding sums over $p_1,p_2$, and interchange the order of summation, noting that we can take $\lambda_{p_1} \overline{\lambda_{p_2}} (\frac{\pm nr}{p_1}) (\frac{\pm nr}{p_1})$ out the front since it doesn't depend on $a$ or $b$. Finally, we take absolute values.
